# New files 'do not stay' on SD card after it is unplugged

Tags: external-sd, sd-card

I insert my SD card used in Android phone to computer and copy or create new files there. It seems that everything is ok but when I unplug it and plug it back in the files are not there - also they cannot be seen from Android of course. What can be the problem ?

Comment: What Android version are you using and is the card encrypted or set as part of the internal storage?

Comment: Probably your SD card is damaged. Do you have data stored in it?